# Android: How to manage multiples Views without XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Im writing an app. I create my own class that extends View, then `setContentView(new MyView());`. Sometimes I want to draw popup with options. Now I draw it with shapes. I was wonder is there a way to make another View or View-like-class and use it as popup?
Another question: Can I use EditText in my own View, also without XML?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use addView method and put new EditText, but be sure about layout params.